# callback_cache.cc(132) Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore - [Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I am trying to run Flutter application after my latest flutter upgrade.

It shows below error

**Runner[58802:2599379] [VERBOSE-1:callback_cache.cc(132)] Could not parse callback cache, aborting restore**

Application shuts after native Splash screen.

In Android platform it works but when trying to run debug app to iOS simulator it gives above error
Flutter LOG

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.18.0-10.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale
en-GB)
• Flutter version 1.18.0-10.0.pre at /Users/harshbhavsar/flutter
• Framework revision a58d50deb1 (3 weeks ago), 2020-04-29 13:04:59 -0700
• Engine revision 2db3276573
• Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-3.0.dev 726d3c7725)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/harshbhavsar/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
  Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
• All Android licenses accepted.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
• CocoaPods version 1.9.1
```

Comment: found any answer for this?

Comment: You need to update your cocoapods and Xcode

Comment: I'm scared that It shouldn't create more mess. but my project was working fine n suddenly after pub upgrade and few libraries it stopped working. Android version is working though

Comment: which version you have?

Comment: xcode 12.3 & COCOAPODS: 1.10.0

Comment: for me.. the solution was.. xcode=> runner => general => deployment info => main interface .. select main in that.. flutter clean and build .